# PL/SQL script running very slow

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql

I have a table `mytable(**id**,colA,colB)` with 5 million records. colA, colB has no other constraints. I have to copy the values in colB to colA and make colB null. Here is the procedure I created below. Some times it runs in 5 minutes and some times it takes 45 minutes. What is wrong with this script? I'm sure that no other process accessing this table during this time. How do I optimize this? ( I know that there will be many other factors that effects the speed of this like DB engine itself slow, may be the machine running at fullcapacity at that time. I'm looking for something that I have in my hands i.e., my script.)

```
 DECLARE


      l_update_total pls_integer := 0;

      CURSOR cur IS SELECT id, colB FROM mytable where colA is null;
      TYPE t_recs IS TABLE OF cur%ROWTYPE;
      l_loop_count pls_integer := 0;
      l_recs t_recs;
      l_rec cur%ROWTYPE;


    BEGIN

       OPEN cur;
       LOOP

            FETCH cur BULK COLLECT INTO l_recs LIMIT 500;

            EXIT WHEN l_recs.COUNT = 0;

            FOR indx IN 1 .. l_recs.COUNT 
            LOOP

                l_rec := l_recs(indx);
                UPDATE mytable SET colB=null,colA = l_rec.colB WHERE id = l_rec.id;
                l_update_total := l_update_total + SQL%ROWCOUNT;


            END LOOP;

            COMMIT;

       END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Whats wrong with the script is it's using cursors...with 5 million records in this format you are running 5 million updates.  SQL is a set based language, not a linear one, so one update of 5 million rows is quicker (probably 500000% faster) than 5 million updates of one row....you will want to rewrite this so it's one statement not 2 loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why aren't you writing a simple SQL statement

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET colB = null,
       colA = colB
 WHERE colA IS NULL;
```

A pure SQL solution is going to be faster than a PL/SQL solution.

If you don't try to understand why your runtimes vary, however, it will be exceptionally difficult to do much to improve performance.  If the system is so overloaded that it adds 40 minutes to the runtime of your procedure and none of that is due to locks (since you claim that no other sessions are reading from or writing to the table in question), it is entirely possible that it will add 40 minutes to the runtime of a single SQL statement.

If you insist on using a slower PL/SQL method, at least take out the `commit` in the loop to avoid incurring that overhead with every batch.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. But Can I really do this? colA also becomes null isnt it? I'll try that on a small set right away.

Comment: @Naresh - The `UPDATE` statement I posted will set `colA` to whatever the old/ existing value of `colB` was and set `colB` to `NULL`.  You won't set `colA` to `NULL` (unless, of course, the existing `colB` value is already `NULL`).

Comment: For those who are curious about this, [SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86668/5).

Answer (score 4):

Dump the cursors and procedural logic, and rewrite it as SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Database queries are not meant to be performed row-by-agonizing-row (RBAR, for Jeff Moden fans). Think about sets of data, not rows.

Technically, a simple update would be better :

```
UPDATE mytable SET colB=null, colA=colB WHERE colA is null
```

Since you seem certain that no other process is touching this table during the operation, locking should not be an issue. Available resources, however, could very well be (considering the number of records).

If performing the operation in a single query is too harsh on the server, try a hybrid solution where you update a few thousand rows at a time, each time using a single UPDATE statement. My PL/SQL days are very far and there have been a lot of T-SQL since then, so I couldn't give you the exact synthax right now, but the idea is still the same.

Comment: How do I update 5 thousands rows at a time? In oder to do that I have to get hold of 5 thousand keys? So I need another query right? Can you point me to some example.

Comment: In Oracle doing one single transaction is almost always faster than doing the update in "chunks" (in contrast to SQL Server). Locking is only an issue if other sessions want to *modify* the values. In Oracle readers never block writers and writers never block readers.